# Is there a way to map rightclick to a hotkey (ctrl+leftclick)?

Tags: touchpad, hotkeys

I am using a thinkpad laptop and I do a lot of 3D modeling in a software where right-click is used a lot, almost as much as left-click but on my laptop's trackpad right-click is a bit harder to click and my hand gets tired after a 1 hour session. I was hoping there would be a way to say click ctrl-leftclick to emulate right-click or something along that vein.

Comment: you mean map `rightclick` to `ctrl + leftclick` ?

Comment: yes. ctrl + leftclick or someother key + leftclick.

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this: 1- Registry hack (needs restart and is persistent) 2- AHK (Which does not use the registry and is not persistent ) .. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I see. Can you please show how to do both? Hopefully, the registry one isnt as risky as it sounds or the persistence one isnt too much hassle on every reboot. I will accept your answer if it helps me solve this issue.

Comment: Looks like the registry hack does not support key combination. Anyway I found a program better than AHK (since it involves programming and other stuff) I will post it right away xD

Comment: You are a lifesaver! My artsy fingers are forever grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Read the whole text because you are going to disable the rightclick!
Go to this website and download the software:
http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm
You can also download the portable version. (preferable)
The program has a friendly interface, you can set for it to make those mapping enabled only when a special software is active (the one that you are working with). Also it has something called Layers. I suggest you to bind those layers to hotkeys (in settings) if you are not using the context sensitive part (I explained above).
So lets start:
1- in the `Right Button` part click on that drop down list and scroll down until you find `Simulated Keys (undefined)` Click on it. (You can also `Add` that software for Context Sensitive mapping - Open that software before clicking `Add`)

[image]

2-Here in the `How to send the simulated keystrokes` part select the third one `3 During (blahblah)`. In the `Enter the custom key(s)` part write this: `{CTRL}{LMB}` Click OK and you are done
The layer 1 is enabled by default, if you have set this on another layer, you should make that enable eighter by setting a hotkey to it (in settings) or from taskbar (which is not the case because you have disabled the right click!)

[image]

Comment: @masterpiece You are welcome! XD